# Is there a way in typescript to only allow anything other than a function that does not return a boolean?

Tags: typescript

So I ran in to an issue where I have a function something like this:

```
function myFunc<T>(filterFnOrObj: T | (x: T) => boolean){
    if (typeof input === 'function') {
        someArray.filter(filterFnOrObj)
    } else {
        someArray.indexOf(filterFnOrObj)
    }
}
```

And what can happen is that if someone passes in a function that isn't really a filter function the code will treat it like a filter since I don't know the return type. I also don't want to ever call the function and see if it returns a boolean.

What I was to do is to prevent people from passing in something that is a function, but isn't a function that return a boolean. Any other type is fine. I'm aware of the conditional types, but I couldn't figure out how to accomplish this using those.

Comment: I think you just need parentheses!  `filterFnOrObj: ((x: T) => boolean) | T`

Comment: Sorry, that was an error in putting the code in to stack overflow, it should have had a parentheses, just didn't get copied and pasted correctly

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try smth like [the code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=28&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgG2BATgdQPYuACxAHgBUA+KAXigApKAPALikIEpzSAjDDBCAQwDsmAKCgioAHyq0GhADRQ4DPgFcAtm1Qsy7Tt35DR4yfUZyFUZWtRyeKFNIDaAXU3auvAYMEAzJXwDGwHAYfFAqIDC+fkTElADOGCoQAIK2PCAOjnJeiMgoMHwA8igFbABW0obwSKiY2HjRLADewqJwXlRwsVW5tbgEJJTZ1XmFxWVMTS0GIvGJKShpAHRDuYM5qPlFJaX6ogC+UBAIsdDN06Kzyakgi3B8ACYQNAVea8ObYztTUHuCv96RQLBeRddboLB9aJSRiVMG9eokJgMGgg2BwiEI0hnUQoCDAJQoEKgSAYdoosgUqAAch8-iBfCpf08fmCsWAIIAogA3CAhCjQizqFBIqAcNz8VhQFEAUigACZyJSAAyCFl8NlQHgIADuaVihBQSmgFCIMhixlk8kUqiF1lsGRFYt0fNIwENEFVrPZuPxhNiACEdO5-UpgGgUMEAOYABRsPBUsXIVGMgqsmvt5htqCcjqDEq0UDdRs96u9eIJ6oAclmUEnKCLU7WCwBGEsan0V2LbOsigBKEBZKHu+DZKDukbkvgA1nwMNq+KQC5RGnshIIwhF-JR7M25HLMpyeR4N5Ft1SeFSD1rdSB9e6hCetzu9weO37A+K+CGwxG+DG4wmD7hKez7ynIADMr7ln61aWMK67AU+jQ8AwzZ7HIjRsAwcp7FBvrqtsQhAA) below. Here're 2 main components:

1. `FilterWorthy` type - it guards you from passing any function which signature isn't suitable for `filter` predicate during compile time
2. `isFilterWorthy` is a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#user-defined-type-guard-functions), it is needed to decide on `filter`/`indexOf` at runtime

```ts
type FilterWorthy<T> = ((x: T) => boolean)
    | ((x: T, i: number) => boolean)
    | ((x: T, i: number, arr: T[]) => boolean)

function myFunc<T>(someArray: T[], filterFnOrObj: T | FilterWorthy<T>) {
    if (isFilterWorthy<T>(filterFnOrObj)) {
        someArray.filter(filterFnOrObj)
    } else {
        someArray.indexOf(filterFnOrObj)
    }
}

function isFilterWorthy<T>(x: T | FilterWorthy<T>): x is FilterWorthy<T> {
    return typeof x === 'function'
}

const isEven = (x: number): boolean => x % 2 === 0
const alwaysTrue = <T,>(x: T, i: number, arr: T[]): boolean => true
const returnsBooleanButWrongParams = (x: number, arr: number[]): boolean => true
const returnsNumber = (): number => 1
const returnsObj = (): Record<string, unknown> => ({})

myFunc([1, 2], isEven)                        // OK
myFunc(['a'], alwaysTrue)                     // OK
myFunc([1, 2], returnsBooleanButWrongParams)  // Error
myFunc([1, 2, 3], returnsNumber)              // Error
myFunc([{a: 1}, {b: 2}], returnsObj)          // Error
```